# Regular expression pattern working in grepl and not in dir

Tags: r, regex

In the following example I define a pattern to look for files having /Data/ in their path and finishing by .dta.

If I use the `dir` command without pattern, according to grepl the files I get match the pattern :

```r
mypattern <- '.*/Data/.*\\.dta'
files <- dir('c:/Temp/Test',recursive=T)

files
#> [1] "dir1/Data/test2.dta" "dir2/Data/test.dta"

grepl(pattern = mypattern, files)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE
```

Why does `dir` with the same pattern return nothing?

```
dir('c:/Temp/Test',pattern = mypattern, recursive=T)
#> character(0)
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : SessionInfo

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 10586)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you give your `sessionInfo`.

Comment: sessionInfo added to my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `dir(pattern=*, recursive=TRUE)`, the `pattern` is applied individually to the file *names* (not paths) for each directory. Try

```
files <- dir(recursive=TRUE)
grep(pattern=pattern, files, values=TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks! returning a full path & testing only filename was confusing to me, but I should have read more carefully the ?dir